# Can an Object type be casted to a Component type?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcomponent

**Scenario :-**

1. Created a `jlist`, contains certain values.
2. Need to pass the `Object test_jL = jlist.getSelectedValue();` to  `JPanel.add(test_jL)`

*Not possible literally as add() accepts* `Component` *type only*

Here is what I am trying to do :-

```
Object test_jList = jXList1.getSelectedValue();
JPanel.removeAll();
JPanel.add(test_jList);  // doesn't matter, as it won't accept an Object type
JPanel.repaint();
JPanel.revalidate();
```

**Question is :-** Can an `Object` type be casted to a `Component`  type ?

I might sound like a noob, but trying to expand my knowledge in Java, so expect your suggestions and ideas to construct the scenario for solving the problem. Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: If it is an instance of `Component`, then yes.

Comment: First explain what you want to achieve: What do you expect to happen when passing a value to JPanel.add ?

Comment: The scenario is that there are `jpanels` based on the the `jList` values. So, I just want to pass a parameter from a `jList` to add(). @LittleSanti

Comment: If `test_jList instanceof Component` is true, you can simply do `jPanel.add((Component) test_jList)`. Otherwise you have to think of something else.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can *attempt* to cast any object to any other object that shares the same inheritance. Object is a superclass of every Object in Java, so you can legally state `MyObject myObj = (MyObject) someOtherObject;` if `someOtherObject` is declared as an Object type.

If, at runtime, `someOtherObject` is a MyObject type, then this cast will work and flow will continue. However, if it's some other type that doesn't share an inheritance with `MyObject` types, then you will get a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) at runtime (which you can catch and react to).

Comment: Both the ojbect are in same class

Comment: Then you should be able to pass it into `JPanel.add()` like so `JPanel.add((Component) test_jList);`

Comment: I have done this : `Object abc = jXList1.getSelectedValue();
        ...;
        JPanel.add((Component)abc);
        .....;
        JPanel.revalidate();`

Comment: It throughs an exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.awt.Component`

Comment: So that means the `.getSelectedValue()` you called didn't return a `Component` but a `String` instead.

Comment: `getSelectedValue()` return an object I guess. And the purpose is to pass the `Object` type to a `Component` type

Comment: In the case you gave, it's returning a `String`. It's interface says it will return an `Object` or anything that inherits from it, depending on the list you're calling it on

Comment: that is very strange indeed

Comment: Read up on "Polymorphism", it will help you understand what's going on here

Comment: I have that in mind. I would love to accept and appreciate the help if any answers have helped me out. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

OK; If you want to pass an argument to a certain panel, forget about add(): That method serves to add a new *visual control* (a textfield, a list, a button, etc) to that panel.

I recommend you extend the JPanel to create your own class:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        super(<layout>);
    }

    public void setParameter(Object parameter)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, instantiate it from the main panel and use its setParameter method to pass the parameter value:

```
public class MyMainPanel extends JPanel
{
    private final MyPanel panel01=new MyPanel();

    public MyMainPanel()
    {
        super(<layout>);
        add(panel01);
    }

    ... listener code...
    {
        Object value = jXList1.getSelectedValue();
        this.panel01.setParameter(value);
    }
}
```

(Note that *setParameter* is not a standard API: Actually you might give it a specific, more semantic name: setBook, setSong, setArtist...)

Comment: **That method serves to add a new visual control (a textfield, a list, a button, etc) to that panel.** .. That's what I need. Many thanks for your effort though but the situation demands me to dynamically pass the `jList.getSelectedValue()` inside `JPanel.add()` . As the `jList.getSelectedValue()`'s name matches   with the name of the `JPanel`

Comment: In that case, you must instantiate a specific visual control before invoking add: Jpanel.add(new JLabel(value.toString())))

Answer (score 0):

This way you can add JPanels to the list and based on the selectionchange on list you can dynamically update the view

```
 public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JList list = new JList();
    list.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {

        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
            p.removeAll();
            p.add((Component) list.getSelectedValue());//dynamically adding panel from list
        }
    }
    );
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
    JPanel x = new JPanel() {
        public String toString() {
            return "xPanel";
        }
    };
    x.add(new JButton("@3"));

    JPanel y = new JPanel() {
        public String toString() {
            return "yPanel";
        }
    };
    y.add(new JTextField(20));

    m.addElement(x);
    m.addElement(y);//adding panel to list
    list.setModel(m);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);

    frame.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

IF you select values from list you can see button and textfield swapping places